# I am getting massive log files in old releases using Envoyer.io

Tags: laravel, logging, laravel-forge, bugsnag, envoyer.io

I am having a strange problem. My error logs in old releases grow to gigabytes with in minutes of deployments. What is strange, is that the releases that grow are the old ones, normally the oldest one. Below is the error that fills the log:

```
[2016-09-22 01:14:48] production.ERROR: ErrorException: include(/home/forge/.../releases/20160922002617/vendor/composer/../bugsnag/bugsnag/src/Report.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/forge/.../releases/20160922002617/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php:414
```

It repeats multiple times per second until I restart the server. I am thinking, that maybe Envoyer isn't restarting a process that is in progress when it switches to a new release. I am not sure where to start on figuring out how I might be able to fix this. I am guessing I need to build something in to the Envoyer "Deployment Hooks".

Has anyone encountered this? Or give me advice on how I might be able ti fix it?

Comment: You will probably find hints by following this checklist : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/php-failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After speaking with Taylor, it was determined that I had old Queue works running off the deleted releases, which was causing the massive amounts of logs. I have added a queue restart script into my embed process and it seems to have fixed the issue. All queues are now restarted after the releases have been activated.